# How to Create WSDL for Restful WS

Tags: rest, wsdl

I have developed a small RESTful web service example using MyEclipse. I want to create a client for those WS using WSDL. How do I create a WSDL for the above web service using MyEclipse? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this resource.  It describes using WSDL 2.0 to describe a REST interface:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/#describerestservice

Answer (score 0):

WSDL ? for a REST web service ? i'd suggest you read this book for a better understanding of REST http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260

You don't need WSDL (nor WADL AFAIC) documentation in rest could be plain text for developers, schemas (xsd, rdfs...etc depending on the content types you use) sitemaps for example, a lot of links and post/put templates for example ( to mimic forms in html)